# offline gps coordinate access - iPhone/Android

Tags: iphone, android, ios, blackberry, mobile

I'm working on a little app, and one of our requirements is to check a users physical location when he did a particular activity (Example: A picture must be taken near Eiffel Tower only)

Now, a lot of our smartphone users might or might not have Data Access at that very instant.

Is it possible to fetch the users Latitude and Longitude when he's offline (No 3G/WiFi).???

I guess the Maps app on iPhone uses data connectivity just to render the underlying Google Maps and the iPhone OS still has access to device's GPS co-ordinates. Please let me know if i'm right or wrong..

I would like to learn the same about other OS'es, example: Android. Any links/references will be much appreciated.

UPDATE: I'm aware that GPS is a satellite based technology and hence i guess it should have no direct relation with internet connectivity.

Comment: You should bear in mind that iOS (and most Android handsets) use A-GPS (assisted GPS), which actually does require a network connection. Without a network connection it could take some time to return a location with any reasonable degree of accuracy.

Comment: Hmmm.. If it takes time for my app to gather the location data - This could be a turn off for my users. I would be interested to know how much time difference there is and if we can send this to a background job or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right!
To get the latitude and longitude Informations the devices use the GPS hardware. **This is done without internet connection**. What you need is a GPS signal! However, if you are inside buildings where you often don't have good GPS signals the iPhone tries to also locate the device using surrounding 3G and WIFI nets.

If you want to display that coordinates for example with google maps you need internet connection to load the maps according to the coordinates you got. Also, to retrieve informations like address,street, etc. the devices needs access to the internet to search the databases for this kind of informations.

**EXAMPLE** for iOS:

Fist import `#import<CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` to you .h file.

Then basically you need the `CLLocationManager`.

```
- (IBAction)startSearchingLocation:(id)sender
{
    //locationManager is ivar of CLLocationManager
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    //release it when you stop the location manager!

    // make self the delegate of the location manager
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    //Note that this settings will have a huge impact on battery life! 
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    //And finally start the location manager.
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

The location Manager will start sending location informations to a delegate method
called:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

It's recommended to throw the very first results away because they could be old cached data. Also check for accuracy to make sure you get good results here.

**REFERENCES:**

For more informations check out [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//#/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) documentation.

Also take a look at the apple example code named `Locations`.

Comment: Well, thanks Braintiff!!! I just need the Latitude and Longitude of the mobile device at the moment. Human readable conversion from [Lat,Lon]  to [Street Address] will be done by my server backend - This will fire up whenever the user gets Internet Connectivity and is ready to sync with our Server. Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your two "this" links are broken so I'm not sure what you were trying to reference.

Answer (score 0):

thats code works with android

```
private double[] getGPS() {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
        List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(false);

        /* Loop over the array backwards, and if you get an accurate location, then break out the loop*/
        Location l = null;

        for (int i=providers.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
                if (l != null) break;
        }

        double[] gps = new double[2];
        if (l != null) {
                gps[0] = l.getLatitude();
                gps[1] = l.getLongitude();
        }
        return gps;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mosh, my question is, will it work Offline? (With no Internet Connectivity? )

Comment: as i know it should work,`lm.getProviders(false);` `false` means offline providers too, it `true` means online only

Comment: Thanks Mosh! That's exactly what i had been thinking